# Java Application as Windows Service

Tags: java, windows, service, daemon

i'd like to define a Java Application as a Windows Service. I got much information and libs for it but i didnt got anything which will allow me to catch Event like restart, shutdown,startUp or else. Can someone give me a hint which library or class i have to use to realise that?

The goal is to build up a "Base" for a implemented Application to become a windows service who allow to catch Events like shutdown or else.

Please be gentle im very new in Service developing.

Im very thankfull for each of your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im using now Yajsw infact of that he is very dynamic and allow to create own Classes for Service wrapping

Answer (score 0):

Please try `Java Service Wrapper` which will fulfil your requirement.

http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/introduction.html#service

Comment: Thank you very much, but i did even noticed it. Do you know any free alternatives?

Comment: Thank you, sorry for asking but can you tell me does it support any hooks for restart,shutdown and start?

Comment: okay, guys question is solved. Thank you very much for your answer. I wull use winrun4j because the license for tanuki ist too expensive when i will update it..

Comment: ...and JavaExe support Windows system event